# MySQL Double many-to-many on an Entity

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-design

I have a project where I have **Products** and **SKU's**. Each Product has one or many SKU's.

I also have **Shops** that can have many to many Products, So a Product can belong to multiple Shops and a Shop can have multiple Products.

To finish, each Shop can choose which SKU's they want for which Products.
So I as a Shop can choose to sell the Tshirt White, which may have (XS,S,M,L) and I can choose (XS,S) as SKU's I want for my Shop.

#### Currently

As you can see A Shop is connected to the Products, and to the SKU's. But I have a feeling there's something wrong

> My shop_skus and shop_products are not connected, So there can be a mismatch between the products a shop has, and the sku's..

**How would I go about fixing that?**

Thank you for your time!

[image]

Comment: Hmm if I understand the problem correctly, you should use pivot table "shop_products" (which by the way should be renamed to "product_shop"), and add that information there.

Comment: so the shop_skus data should be moved inside the product_shop?

Comment: Try Jeff's solution, which I would end up in the end with. Did not read the problem through and through.

Comment: can't this all be solved with two inner joins and group by?

Comment: @cmorrissey sure, but OP probably wants to use Eloquent ORM and not bother with raw SQL.

Comment: I'm okay with whatever solution! I'm especially interested in good db design.. Thank you guys!

Comment: @cmorrissey I think it can not, since in current design there is no information on which SKUs does shop support per product, so pure SQL solution is not possible, schema must be altered.

Comment: Optimal design of a many-to-many mapping table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 2):

If each shop has a set of products, and each shop-product relation has a set of SKUs, I think you need to use an intermediate model to handle the relationship.  You could create a model called `CarriedProduct` which has relations to a shop, a product, and a one-to-many relationship with SKUs.

Normally, to add additional information to a relation, ie. Shop->Product, you would use pivot columns in the relation table.  But since there are multiple skus, pivot columns wont cut it.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of that solution. I'm going to give it a try, thank you!

Comment: @Notflip There is this integrity thing that if one product gets amended in a way that skus is removed, app "AI" (that means OP) needs to check & remove all the other "links" to shops as well. I am just pointing it out so OP does not bite himself in a leg.

Comment: @kyslik I think using proper Laravel relations will prevent this from causing any errors in your code, and using proper foreign keys will keep the database clean and tidy.  Shouldn't need to do too much management on that front.

Comment: FK's constraints sure, but "proper Laravel relations" will not cut it, I don't think Laravel does any kind of sync by default + we are talking about entities which are out of scope of each other (product-sku and product-sku-shop), so without proper schema (constraints) OP may end up with a "CarriedProduct" which can not be manufactured at all.

Comment: If I understand correctly the solution, the `CarriedProduct` is what the OP aleady has as `shop_product`. But you suggest he gets rid of the `sku` and `shop_skus` tables and have a single `carriedproduct_skus` table for the SKU info (it will the many side on the relationship with `CarriedProduct`). Do I understand correctly the suggestion?

Comment: It sounds reasonable and could solve the issue, with one restriction/change: They won't be able to have an sku_id that is shared by many shops. Each shop that has a specific product, will use different sku_ids (for the same product). That off course may be fine with the OP and they can use the suggestion.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes that is what I am suggesting.  But no, there does not need to be a separate SKU id per product.  There is still a `skus` table, and the `carriedproduct_skus` table will reference the `id` column.

Comment: And how will you enforce consistency? I mean what forbids an item in `carriedproduct_skus` to reference a product and a sku that itself references a different product?

Comment: I agree on the design by the way. That's similar to what I already suggested. But it needs composite FKs, as in Paul's answer, if they want to enforce consistency at the db level.

Comment: I see a difference between this answer, and paul's answer. Are they both correct given good database design? If we use the composite keys?

Answer (score 2):

> My shop_skus and shop_products are not connected, So there can be a
>   mismatch between the products a shop has, and the sku's

As far as I understand, you have two indirect relations between shops and products: `shops -> shop_skus -> skus -> products` and `shops -> shop_products -> products`. The consistency issue can be fixed with composite foreign keys.

- Add the column `shop_skus.product_id`
- Define composite foreign keys:

  1. `shop_skus(product_id, sku_id) -> skus(product_id, id)`
  2. `shop_skus(shop_id, product_id) -> shop_products(shop_id, product_id)`

The order of the columns in the keys can be changed. It depends on what indexes would be of a better use for your queries.

With those foreign keys you can only insert shop-skus which have rerlation to both tables: `shop_products` and `skus`.

#### Update

If I understand your comments correctly, you need a relation between the shops SKUs and the product slugs.

Example: Some shop is selling

```
product     | slug        | SKUs
------------|-------------|-----
white shirt | Batman      | M,L
white shirt | Wonderwomen | XS,S
```

In this case I would do the following:

- Add AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY `shop_products.id`
- Add the column `shop_skus.product_id`
- Add the column `shop_skus.product_shops_id`
- Define composite foreign keys:

  1. `shop_skus(product_id, sku_id) -> skus(product_id, id)`
  2. `shop_skus(product_id, product_shop_id) -> shop_products(product_id, id)`

You can/should also drop the folowing foreign key if it exists:

- `shop_skus(sku_id) -> skus(id)`

Since it would be redundant.

Comment: Thank you! That does seem right, do you have any reference or place where I can find the correct SQL statements to query those tables. I'm guessing in Laravel, Eloquent won't be able to handle this.

Comment: @Notflip What do you mean? CREATE statements for the FKs?

Comment: No How I can query them, but I'm going to look into it tonight! Going to try some queries. thank you very much!

Comment: @Notflip For SELECT statements nothing needs to be changed. INSERT and UPDATE statements need to manage only one more column.

Comment: Thank for your time, I'm having trouble in Laravel defining the relations. I guess it's better to resort to raw sql for this?

Comment: I think most things can be done in laravel. But it's too much for a comment and offtopic as an answer. If you've been stuck somewhere, you can still ask a new question on SO.

Comment: Hi Paul, One more issue I came across, A Shop is allowed to have many shop_products with the same product_id, the same shop_id, but a different slug.. the issue now is that the shop_skus is throwing errors for duplicate keys, because Product 1, for Shop 1, with the slug of Slug1 will have the same SKU record as Product 1 for Shop 1, with the slug of Slug 2.. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Notflip I don't understand the business logic of a shop having the same product with different names/slugs/what-ever. However -  A foreign key should only reference a unique key. If `shop_products(shop_id, product_id)` is not (at least logically) unique, you will need another table (something like `shop_unique_products`) where `(shop_id, product_id)` is unique (or PK). Then you can define FKs `shop_skus(shop_id, product_id) -> shop_unique_products(shop_id, product_id)` and `shop_products(shop_id, product_id) -> shop_unique_products(shop_id, product_id)`.

Comment: Well it's a dropship, so a Supplier offers Products with SKU's, And a Shop can pick Products and choose which SKU's of the Supplier he picks, does that make sense? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. How are slugs and SKUs related, other than by product_id?

Comment: Oh a Shop can have 2x the same Product, but with a different Print for example. a Batman tshirt :product 1 (tshirt), sku 1 (small), slug: batman, or a Wonder woman: product 1(tshirt), sku 1 (small), slug: wonderwoman

Comment: So the shop chooses SKUs for a product/slug combination?